# replace text on filename on folders

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have these filenames  and I want to replace this text SYPTE1-PC  to SHEFFIELD and in this format.

PRESENT FORMAT

```
1UYK08HJ_20140403165858071_SYPTE1-PC.jpg ,
1YK0BHJX_20140403165902791_SYPTE1-PC.jpg
```

REQUIRED FORMAT

```
1UYK08HJ_SHEFFIELD_2014_04_03_16:58:58:071.jpg
1YK0BHJX__SHEFFIELD_2014_04_03_16:59:02:791.JPG`
```

this is my query

```
@echo off
pushd "C:\Users\IT-Administrator\Desktop\export" || exit /b
for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=_." %%A in ('dir /b /a-d *_*.jpg') do (
  Echo ren %%A_%%B_%%C.%%D %%A_%%C_%%B.%%D
)
popd
```

I am able to change the format but cannot replace text and datetime with colons.

Comment: You cannot have `:` characters in filenames

Comment: is it possible to replace just the text...

Comment: Yes, are the files in a single folder or spread out in a folder tree?

Comment: In a a single folder tree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will create `renfiles.bat.txt` for you to examine and rename to `.bat` and execute if you are happy with it.

It uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.

```
@echo off
dir *.jpg /b /a-d |find /i /v "%~nx0" |find /i /v "repl.bat" |repl "(.*?_)(....)(..)(..)(..)(..)(..)(...).*(\..*)" "ren \q$&\q \q$1SHEFFIELD_$2_$3_$4-$5_$6_$7_$8$9\q" xa >"renfiles.bat.txt"
```

Comment: Thats excatly what i want but ... i get these in renfiles.bat.txt . I saved it as .bat and when i run it  i get` C:\Users\IT-Administrator>ren "YK08HJX_20140403170543114_SYPTE.jpg" "YK08HJX_SHE
FFIELD_2014_04_03-17_05_43_114.jpg"
The system cannot find the file specified.`

Comment: but these files are there

Comment: `renfiles.bat` has to be run in the same folder as the files.

Comment: Foxidrive i was workign on this script it worked for me for new images when there are new images in the same folder  with the existing changed name files it was not working.

Comment: If the filename format changes then the regular expression needs to change too.

Comment: If you tell me the formats of the filenames then I can help.  I'm not sure what has changed in your filenames.